# comment threading in couchdb with view collation

Tags: multithreading, comments, couchdb

I'm working on a comment system in couchdb, and have successfully gotten threading to work one level deep, but beyond that I"m not sure how to do it?

I have a feeling it should be along the lines of linked documents here: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views

Can anyone point me in a direction on how to do comment system multi-level deep?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing comments have unique comment id's and threads have unique thread id's.  They both also have some sort of a timestamp.

Say you have this happen:

```
thread (thread_id := 1)
comment (c_id := 1, c_time := 1, t_id := 1)
    comment (c_id := 2, c_time := 2, t_id := 1, c_parent := 1)
        comment (c_id :=4, c_time := 3, t_id := 1, c_parent := 2)
    comment (c_id := 3, c_time := 4, t_id := 1, c_parent := 1)
```

With that sort of structure your view would just query by t_id (thread id), if you retrieve the documents ordered by the comment time stamp you can easily create a list of root comments and from there create your tree of comments for the thread.

Comment: I guess I"m struggling with the map reduce part... more so the reduce, I can return all the comments but getting them to appear in the correct thread is the issue.